# c# if key exist in dictionary still add the value in dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

From a datatable I am fetching the value and putting in a `Dictionary<string,string>`:

```
Dictionary<string, string> mydic= new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

my datatable for ex is

```
Value     RowOrder    
page1       01 
page2       00
page3       00
```

I am using LINQ to fetch the `RowOrder` according to value given and putting into `mydic`:

```
string id = (from DataRow dr in table3.Rows where (string)dr["Value"] == formula
             select (string)dr["RowOrder"]).FirstOrDefault();
mydic.Add(id,Value);
```

If I run this, error is showing:

> "An item with the same key has already been added."

How to overcome this. I want `page1`, `page2`, `page3` should be added with values `01`, `00`, `00` respectively

Comment: A dictionary can't have duplicate keys, so it's up to you to decide what should happen in that case.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. The point of a dictionary is to be able to look up items by the key. How could that ever work if you add multiple items with the same key? What do you expect to see if you check `mydic["00"]`?

Comment: If you have duplicate keys then what's the point of using Dictionary??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to check whether the dictionary already has the key before adding to it:

```
if(!mydic.ContainsKey(id))
{
    mydic.Add(id, Value);
}
```

A dictionary cannot contain two items with the same key, if you are expecting duplicate id values you need to consider using a different data structure.

Perhaps a `List<Tuple<string, string>>`?

Comment: @user2380844 No problem, `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` is a nice idea.

Answer (score 3):

Check if key exists before adding

```
if (mydic.ContainsKey(id))
    mydic[id] = Value; // or throw exception        
else
    mydic.Add(id, Value);
```

BTW if you want to convert your `DataTable` to `Dictionary<string, string>` with *RowOrder* as key, and first (or last) *Value* as value, you can use LINQ:

```
var mydic = table3.AsEnumerable()
                  .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("RowOrder"))
                  .Select(g => g.First()) // or last to use last value for key
                  .ToDictionary(r => r.Field<string>("RowOrder"),
                                     r.Field<string>("Value"));
```

Comment: I know that the GroupBy will return an IEnumerable<IGrouping<string,TableRow>>, is that right? if so, I can't get what the rest of code is doing. May you please explain.

Comment: @mrida rest is selecting first row from each group, thus we are avoiding duplicate keys issue. Then sequence of rows is converted to dictionary

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GroupBy`, here a single line approach using `Linq-To-DataSet`:

```
Dictionary<string, string> mydic = table3.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(row => row.Field<string>("Value"))
    .ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.First().Field<string>("RowOrder"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
mydic[id] = Value;
```

instead of mydic.Add();
The Add method should be used if you want to ensure only one item with a given key is inserted.
Note that this overwrite the previously written value.

If you want to have more items with the same key you should use a

```
Dictionary<string, IList<string>>
```

or some other datastructure I don't know of but I would be very glad to hear about since I used that kind of dictionary more than once

Answer (score 0):

You may use a `Lookup<string,string>`:

```
List<Tuple<string, string>> tuples = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
tuples.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("01", "page1"));
tuples.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("00", "page2"));
tuples.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("00", "page3"));
var lookup = tuples.ToLookup(t => t.Item1,t=> t.Item2 );
```

And you may use it like:

```
var result = lookup["00"];
foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> page2
> page3
> ```